# Count SQL Query Records

Tags: sql, database, group-by, count, having-clause

I have a problem that I need to identify how many companies participated in a given project number. For example, identify which companies participated in exactly 2 projects.

Given the base below:

```
id company project  
1 company1 project1
2 company2 project1
3 company3 project2
4 company1 project2
5 company2 project2
6 company2 project3
7 company3 project1
8 company1 project1
9 company2 project2
10 company1 project2
```

How to use a SQL query to solve this problem? For this case above, the query is expected to return:

```
company1
company2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregate by `company` and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select company
from mytable
group by company
having count(project) = 2
```

If the same project may occur twice for a given company, then you want `count(distinct project)` instead of `count(project)`.

Answer (score 2):

You use `group by` and `having`:

```
select company
from t
group by company
having count(distinct project) = 2;
```